# Code Igniter RESTful Modeling and Controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have been developing using non framework for about 3 years and I have heard about PHP framework codeigniter.

I think I missed something using this framework which is used for API for my mobile application.

I've facing some problem to get data from database using Phil's CI framework, RESTful plugin. My browser shows error code:

```
 {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}
```

Using my logic below:

controller: user.php

```
  <?php

  require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

  class User extends REST_Controller{

  public function user_get()  
  {  
    //IF USER NOT EXIST
    if(!$this->get('id'))
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }

    //CHECK TO MODEL FUNCTION
    $user = $this->user_model->get_user($this->get('id'));

    //IF USER EXIST
    if($user)
    {
        $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }
}  

   public function user_put()  
   {  
    // create a new user and respond with a status/errors  
   }  

   public function user_post()  
   {  
    // update an existing user and respond with a status/errors  
   }  

   public function user_delete()  
   {  
    // delete a user and respond with a status/errors  
   }  
 }
?>
```

model: user_model.php

```
 <?php

    class User_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();        
    }

    function get_user($id){
        $query = $this->db->get('mt_user', array('idmt_user'=>$id));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

   }
   ?>
```

i'm accessing the database which is has this rows:

```
idmt_user,username,password, emails, createdate
```

accessed using mozilla:

```
@http://localhost/<project>/index.php/user/<userid>
```

Where's the error(s) ?

thanks.

**update,** 
i am already defined the autoloads for database. But this problem still persist. Is there any helps? thanks

as stated below in answer, i tried to access the url, /user/get_user/ but still showing the same result. Is there any problem using idmt_user in database?

Comment: looks like your router is not routing to the correct method

Comment: how fix it then @user1281385 ? i'm using codeigniter default routing functions.

Comment: is there any error causing id in database?

Answer (score 1):

Insert in controllers:

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
}
```

And try this route:

> http://localhost//index.php/user/user/id/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the url you are accessing with is wrong.. Try accessing with the url `@http://localhost/<project>/index.php/user/<method_name>/<user_id>`

Comment: So for example <project>/index.php/user_get/<id> You aren't accepting any parameters in the function though, so I'm not too sure. You may need to look into how controllers work a little bit more. they are a fairly simple concept once you look into them.

Comment: i've tried accessing the url using this: /user/user_get/1 and /user_get/1 but both is showing the same results.

Comment: Make sure you are putting variables up through get!

Comment: User_get is accessed when user has been requested with get. User_post when it has been accessed with post for example

Comment: what do you mean putting var through get? from the browser parameter? or refactoring the controller? i've add the parameter in the url by the way, coz i'm new to this framework

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be using the URI Class.

Instead of writing the following:

```
//IF USER NOT EXIST
if(!$this->get('id'))
{
    $this->response(NULL, 400);
}
```

Changed to:

```
$userid = $this->uri->segment(3);

Would be 3 based off the url being http://localhost/<project>/user/<method_name>/<user_id>
```

Reference for URI Class: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

In order to use $this->get(); there would have to be a query parameter to get. Example: id=

If you are passing query parameters than you could store these values in a array as shown below.

```
if(!empty($this->get()))
{
    $params[] = $this->get();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should to try include your model file into your controller file by using a __construct() function, like this:

```
function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model(array('user_model'));
}
```